# How to add btn btn-primary class to anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to add `btn btn-primary` class to the `anchor taq`
This is my code but its not working.

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="?pageno=1" >First</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Have you added Bootstrap reference?

Comment: post your css, html can not tell the styling issue.

Comment: i have added boostrap cdn link

Comment: if you post your complete code, then you will know the problem. but anyway see here, if you have added the css library in the right, it must work as https://jsfiddle.net/sa4tbwkf/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the bootstrap from the local pc. then you go to `bootstrap.min.css`. And search and replace this code `.btn-primary{color:#fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4;}` 
with  That code, I am sure it will work for you.

```
.btn-primary{color:#fff; background-color: #337ab7!important; border-color: #2e6da4!important;}
```

Comment: It's a really bad idea to edit the Bootstrap CSS files directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this :

```
<a href="?pageno=1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">First</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Unnecessary to be a `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

add boostrap reference inside your `<head>` tag

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Add Full Bootstrap</title>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>    
<body>

<h1>Bootstrap Pagination</h1>

<ul class="pagination">
   <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
   <li class="<?php if ($pageno <= 1) {
      echo 'disabled';
   } ?>">
      <a href="<?php if ($pageno <= 1) {
         echo '#';
      } else {
         echo "?pageno=" . ($pageno - 1);
      } ?>">Prev</a>
   </li>
   <li class="<?php if ($pageno >= $total_pages) {
      echo 'disabled';
   } ?>">
      <a href="<?php if ($pageno >= $total_pages) {
         echo '#';
      } else {
         echo "?pageno=" . ($pageno + 1);
      } ?>">Next</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

For more, go to [Getting started Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)